# Manage multiple association of two classes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I want to manage the association of one to many type, for user and answers and association of many to many type, for vote management for the same two models i.e users and answers.

So, how to maintain both the associations at the same time?

This code is something that I want to implement.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    

 has_many :answers #For the answers of particular user

 has_and_belongs_to_many :answers #For the answers upvoted by a particular user

 end 

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user #Author of the answer

 has_and_belongs_to_many :users #For those who upvoted the answer

end
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @DaveNewton Actually when a user 'u' will upvote, then i want to add that answer to the u.answers (that he has upvoted not the answer written by him) but user u.answers can't be used for both associations :(

Comment: Then you need two associations, not just one. Check out the options in the AR guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give a different name to the other association, but then you would also need to specify class name.

```
has_many :answers
has_and_belongs_to_many :voted_answers, class_name: "Answer"
```